# Do I need to SubmitChanges after executing a stored procedure with Linq-To-Sql?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

Linq-To-Sql enables calling SPs. If this SP executes an update/delete/insert, do I need to SubmitChanges() after it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No you don't. The code will work. Submit changes is only concerned with modified LINQ to SQL objects and not stored procs.